# PHPExcel - How to replace text using preg_replace

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to extract data from my database onto an organized Excel sheet. Everything is working great except for one thing. My database entries can sometimes contain HTML markups like `<strong></strong>`, `<BR>`, `<p></p>` etc ... So I managed to get this PHP line working, this is working great to replace my `<BR>` markups to a space.

```
$data = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $data);         
$data = str_replace("<br/>", "\n", $data);          
$data = str_replace("<br>", "\n", $data);
```

However when I try doing the following it does nothing. I was expecting that it would bold the text.

```
$data = str_replace("<strong>", '&B', $data);
```

I read on these forums that its best to use preg_replace and setup an array for all the HTML markups I need replaced. For the life of me I can't understand how to use preg_replace. Would someone please give me some advise what is the best way to replace markups such as `<strong>` and `</strong>` to bold when it exports, this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need something like this: `$data = "<strong>testtest<strong><strong>";
 
  echo $data = preg_replace("/<strong>/", '&B', $data);` ?

Comment: That worked like a charm it replaced all strong markups with &B. I was expecting that PHPExcel would bold the text but it just added &B as text. Would you know why that would be?

Comment: Sry don't know anything about phpexecel... I only know how to use preg_replace. What you have to use as a replacement i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'&B'` will only set bold text for printed page headers and footers, as described in the section of the documentation entitled `Setting the print header and footer of a worksheet`

Formatting the content of a cell is described in the section of the documentation entitled `Formatting cells`, something like:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('bold');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

or (if your content contains actual markup) using Rich Text objects if you only want to set part of the text to bold.

```
$objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
$objRichText->createText('This text is ');

$objBoldTextRun = $objRichText->createTextRun('bold');
$objBoldTextRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->setValue($objRichText);
```

but you will need to parse your markup to convert it to a Rich Text object